# spring: how to add a property of a bean as a constructor arg

Tags: spring, inversion-of-control, javabeans

I have a bean (bean1) which has a method called getProperties()

I need to pass the value of getProperties() as a constructor arg of another bean

Something like:

```
<constructor-arg ref="bean1.properties"/>
```

which does now work.
How can I do it?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Spring Expression Language for this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html).

Example:

```
<constructor-arg value="#{bean1.properties}"/>
```

Comment: since it's "value" I'm wondering if changes made on the "properties" object will be propagated on both beans

Comment: Depends on the return type of the bean1.properties call. If a reference will be returned, e.g. to java.util.Properties, then yes, changes will be propagated.